# How to bind view from constructor in ViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Could you please help me to bind views in view holder. I have read existing answer but not sure how to implement it in my case.

My holder looks like this and I don't have onCreateViewHolder

```
class MyViewHolder(
    itemView: View,
    private val myListener: MyListener
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val myLabel: AppCompatTextView = itemView.**findViewById**(R.id.myLabel)//**here need to remove findviewbyId**

    fun bindView() {
        itemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.image)

        myLabel.setOnClickListener {
            myListener.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, what you are missing is the binding in the constructor

```
class MyViewHolder(
    private val binding: YourLayoutBinding, //you can access it because is private val
    ...
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) { //You need the view so pass the root view of the binding

    //change your view to binding dot view
    fun bindView() {
        binding.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.image) //in this case the background seems data binding so I'm treating it as such

        binding.myLabel.setOnClickListener {
            myListener.myMethod()
        } //but here myLabel is a view contained inside the binding
    }
}
```

And you are probably gonna have doubts regarding the `onCreateViwHolder`

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = YourLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding, ...)
    }
```

The trick is the bindings have an static method to inflate them

Comment: thank you. But how I can get an access to the view in this place?    
itemView.**findViewById**(R.id.myLabel) //<-- I must call root here? instead of findViewById?

Comment: I specifically add comments for that, your binding is a field so you can access it in the class, read the comment on the constructor, you can access your label view by accessing the binding as well with `binding.myLabel` look at the `bindView` function.